# Simple yet Hackable WhatsApp API [UNOFFICIAL]

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, web-scraping, selenium

There is no official WhatsApp API. Here is a simple python class which satisfies the need.

```
# SWAMI KARUPPASWAMI THUNNAI

#============================================================
# Simple yet Hackable! WhatsApp API [UNOFFICIAL] for Python3
# Note: The author gives permission to use it under Apache2.0
#============================================================

import time
import datetime as dt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

class Emoji:
    """
    This class is used to send emoji's to whatsapp
    """
    emoji = {}
    # We will load our emojis in the constructor
    def __init__(self):
        self.emoji[':thumbsup:'] = "(y)"
        self.emoji[':-1:'] = "(n)"
        self.emoji[':simple_smile:'] = ":-)"
        self.emoji[':worried:'] = ":-("
        self.emoji['stuck_out_tongue:'] = ":-p"
        self.emoji[':laughing:'] = ":-d"
        self.emoji[':heart:'] = "<3"
        self.emoji[':neutral_face:'] = ":-|"
        self.emoji[':wink:'] = ";-)"

    # This method is used to emojify all the text emoji's present in the message
    def emojify(self,message):
        emojies = self.emoji.keys()
        for emoji in emojies:
            message = message.replace(emoji,self.emoji[emoji])
        return message


class WhatsApp:
    """
    This class is used to interact with your whatsapp [UNOFFICIAL API]
    """
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    def __init__(self,wait,screenshot=None):
        self.browser.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/")
        time.sleep(wait)
        if screenshot != None:
            self.browser.save_screenshot(screenshot) # This will save the screenshot to the specified file location

    # This method is used to send the message to the individual person or a group
    # will return true if the message has been sent, false else
    def send_message(self,name,message):
        emoji = Emoji() # create an emoji object
        message = emoji.emojify(message) # this will emojify all the emoji which is present as the text in string
        search = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("input-search")
        search.send_keys(name+Keys.ENTER) # we will send the name to the input key box
        current_time = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                send_msg = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("input")
                send_msg.send_keys(message+Keys.ENTER) # send the message
                return True
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            new_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = new_time - current_time
            if elapsed_time > 30:
                return False

    # This method will count the no of participants for the group name provided
    def participants_for_group(self,group_name):
        search = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("input-search")
        search.send_keys(group_name+Keys.ENTER) # we will send the name to the input key box
        current_time = time.time()
        while True:
            try:
                click_menu = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("header.pane-header:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                click_menu.click()
                participants_css_selector = "div.animate-enter2:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2)"
                participants_count = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(participants_css_selector).text
                if "256" in participants_count:
                    return participants_count
                else:
                    time.sleep(1)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            new_time = time.time()
            elapsed_time = new_time - current_time
            if elapsed_time > 100:
                return "NONE" 

    # get the status message of a person 
    # TimeOut is approximately set to 10 seconds
    def get_status(self,name,timeout=10):
        search = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("input-search")
        search.send_keys(name+Keys.ENTER) # we will send the name to the input key box
        start_time = dt.datetime.now()
        while True:
            try:
                click_menu = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("header.pane-header:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)")
                click_menu.click()
                # This is the css selector for status
                status_selector = "div.animate-enter2:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)"
                status = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(status_selector).text
                # if the status if obtained the length must be greater than 0
                if len(status) > 0:
                    return status
            except Exception as e:
                pass
            end_time = dt.datetime.now()
            elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time).seconds
            if elapsed_time > timeout:
                raise TimeoutError("The response has been TimedOut. You may change the time-out specifying in your args.")

    # to get the last seen of the person
    def get_last_seen(self,name,timeout=10):
        search = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("input-search")
        search.send_keys(name+Keys.ENTER) # we will send the name to the input key box
        start_time = dt.datetime.now()
        last_seen_css_selector = ".chat-subtitle-text"
        while True:
            try:
                last_seen = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector(last_seen_css_selector).text
                if len(last_seen) > 0:
                    if "click here" in last_seen:
                        pass
                    else:
                        return last_seen
            except Exception as e:
                pass

            end_time = dt.datetime.now()
            elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time).seconds
            if elapsed_time > timeout:
                raise TimeoutError("The response has been TimedOut. You may change the time-out specifying in your args.")


    # This method is used to quit the browser
    def quit(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

**Examples: You can achieve many thing less than five lines of code**

**Sending a message with an emoji:**

```
from whatsapp import WhatsApp
whatsapp = WhatsApp(10)
print(whatsapp.send_message("Name",":heart: Good!"))
```

Result:

[image]

**Getting the status message of a person:**

```
from whatsapp import WhatsApp
whatsapp = WhatsApp(10)
print(whatsapp.get_status("Oracle"))
```

Result: Have a nice day!

**Getting last seen of a person:**

```
from whatsapp import WhatsApp
whatsapp = WhatsApp(10)
print(whatsapp.get_last_seen("Oracle"))
```

Result: last seen today 11:34 pm

**Getting the no of participants in the group:**

```
from whatsapp import WhatsApp
whatsapp = WhatsApp(10)
result = whatsapp.participants_for_group("group")
```

Result: 3 of 256

**Advantages:**

1. Limited emoji support is provided.
2. The library itself hackable, you can use python lists to send messages to various persons or you can loop for a person's last seen status and if the status comes "Online" you can greet him a message. You can monitor the participants in the group in a loop and greet if new participants are added.

Comment: for anyone in future interested in this code may use this code from here: https://github.com/VISWESWARAN1998/Simple-Yet-Hackable-WhatsApp-api/blob/master/whatsapp.py I have updated my code meeting the suggestions of the below answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a collection of things to improve.

#### Code Style Notes

Overall, there is a number of [PEP8 Code Style violations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), like lack of spaces around operators, blank lines, spaces before the `#` comment character etc. Make sure to address them. You can also use tools like [`flake8`](http://flake8.pycqa.org/) or [`pylint`](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to statically analyze code for common PEP8 and other code quality issues.

Some other Code Style related notes:

- `WebDriverWait` is unused - this time, don't remove it but rather use it instead of `time.sleep()` - more about it later below
- [be specific about what exceptions you are handling avoiding catching bare `Exception` errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14797375/771848) - for instance, you should rather be catching either [`WebDriverException`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException) than `Exception` in your browser interaction methods.
- use `is` when comparing to `None`; for instance, replacing:

  ```
  if screenshot != None:
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if screenshot is not None:
  ```
- you can simplify the emptiness checks. For example, you can replace:

  ```
  if len(last_seen) > 0:
      if "click here" in last_seen:
          pass
      else:
          return last_seen
  ```

  with:

  ```
  if last_seen and "click here" not in last_seen:
      return last_seen
  ```
- you don't need to call `.keys()` on the dictionary and then iterate over them - you can iterate over the keys by directly iterating over the dictionary:

  ```
  for emoji in self.emoji:
  ```
- avoid hardcoding things inside your implementations - move "magic" numbers like these timeout values inside the browser interaction methods to proper constants (or use that `timeout` argument to compare with the elapsed time)

#### Selenium-specific Improvements

- instead of hardcoding wait timeouts and using `time.sleep()`, use [`WebDriverWait` which implements an Explicit Wait functionality](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). There is a number of [built-in Expected Conditions](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) to wait for (and it's easy to write your own one) - for instance, you may wait for an element to be present or visible, button or link to be clickable etc.

  `time.sleep()` is seriously unreliable - it tends to wait more than you usually need and fails randomly when the timeout was not enough.

  And, I don't think you should parameterize your class with a `wait` value.
- you should tie the browse instance to your class instance and not the class itself - initialize `browser` inside the `__init__()` constructor of the `WhatsApp` class
- *your CSS selectors are too fragile* because they depend on the HTML structure of the page too much. Try to improve the quality and reliability of your locators, some tips to get you started: [What makes a good selenium locator?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/27978/5574)

#### Other Things

- I don't really see the need for `Emoji` to be a class. For me, it would be perfectly fine to have it in a dictionary or even in a separate JSON or YAML config file. `emojify()` can simply be a utility function. More on the subject of when to use classes and when not:

  - [Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)
  - [Start Writing More Classes](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/2/13/moar-classes/)
- or, you can take it a step further and use the [`emoji` third-party library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/emoji/)

<sup>note</sup> I don't use WhatsApp and may be missing some context-specific things here.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have addressed most of your suggestions. Here is a completed code: https://github.com/VISWESWARAN1998/Simple-Yet-Hackable-WhatsApp-api/blob/master/whatsapp.py  I've acknowledged you!